# PHPStorm code templates

Tags: templates, phpstorm

I am trying to customize default setter template in PHPStorm.

I want to add `return $this;` line into setter template, but a blank line I inserted into template is ignored by editor
How can I insert a blank line before return statement in setter template?

Answer (score 12):

Enable option "Blank line before return statement" in: Settings -> Code Style -> PHP -> Other